# Parameterizing $y = 2 -\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

I am trying to parametrize the part of the curve 
$$
y = 2 -\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}
$$ from (0, 2) to (1, 1).

I tried the difficult paramaterization  $x=t$ and obtained
$$
y=2-\sin \frac{\pi t}{2} 
$$
but am unable to see how to use $(0,2$ to $(1,1)$ and what to integrate form here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $x(t)=t$ can often work, which would set $y(t)=2-\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$.  The only downside is that perhaps there might be a different parametrization that makes some of the algebra and arithmetic involved a little easier (or even the calculus).

As for going from the points, $(0,2)$ to $(1,1)$., the question would be at what time, $t$ is it at each point.  Since $t=x$, you have that $0\leq t \leq 1$.

A followup question would be if the question asks what is the arc-length of the curve, or the area under the curve.

In the case that it asks the area under the curve, you can set it up as $\int\limits_0^1 2-\sin\frac{\pi t}{2} dt$.

If it is asking for arclength then you have $s(t) = \int\limits_a^t \sqrt{x'(\tau)^2 + y'(\tau)^2} d\tau = \int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \frac{\pi^2}{4}cos^2 \frac{\pi\tau}{2}}d\tau$ and continuing from there.

Comment: Great thank you.  I understand $x=t$ may not be the simplest, but it does give the same as any other parametrization, correct?  This arc length in terms of elliptic functions.

Comment: It can be proven that any two parametrizations are equivalent, yes.  The answer doesn't depend on the parametrization.  Sometimes though, a particular parametrization will be more useful so as to provide a convenient $u$-substitution that might not have been so obvious otherwise, for example changing from cartesian x,y coordinates to polar r,$\theta$ coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I checked it as the answer.  This solution makes sense!